# Accessing GCP Memorystore from local machines

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-memorystore

Whats the best way to access Memorystore from Local Machines during development? Is there something like Cloud SQL Proxy that I can use to set up a tunnel?

Comment: it's disappointing that you can't connect to this cloud redis instance without paying to create another intermediate instance

Answer (score 65):

You can spin up a Compute Engine instance and use port forwarding to connect to your Redis machine.

For example if your Redis machine has internal IP address 10.0.0.3 you'd do:

```
gcloud compute instances create redis-forwarder --machine-type=f1-micro
gcloud compute ssh redis-forwarder -- -N -L 6379:10.0.0.3:6379
```

As long as you keep the ssh tunnel open you can connect to localhost:6379

Update: this is now officially documented:
https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance#connecting_from_a_local_machine_with_port_forwarding

Comment: I can create instance but while running the second command I am getting this below error :

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not SSH into the instance.  It is possible that your SSH key has not propagated to the instance yet. Try running this command again.  If you still cannot connect, verify that the firewall and instance are set to accept ssh traffic.

Comment: This is great .

Comment: Why isn't this the accepted answer? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_server

Comment: Just used this yesterday. Was literally as easy as installing the GCP tool and running these two commands. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, when I run the second command the CLI just hangs forever. Any ideas what it might be?

Comment: @Josh Might need to check if the GCE instance is running in the same zone as your Redis instance.

Comment: `redis-cli` does connect, but if I try to run any command like `get <key>` or `cluster info` I get `Error: Connection reset by peer`

Comment: Beautiful! Wish Google had this documented.

Comment: @Christiaan should we take into consideration also the machine type for bandwidth ingress and egress right?

Comment: @Riccardo yes, if you need a lot of bandwidth for this tunnel you might want a bigger machine than an f1-micro.

Comment: Doesn't this approach increase the time required to fetch the data from Redis instead of a direct connection to the REDIS server?

Comment: @Shriram probably. But a direct connection isn't possible since Redis isn't exposed on an external IP. Also for dev use cases the extra 1ms or so probably doesn't matter.

Comment: @Josh you have to make sure you create the redis-forwarder in the same network as your redis-network. Check in the memorystore console and copy the `Authorized Network` name. then add it with `gcloud compute instances create redis-forwarder --network-interface network=[Authorized Network] --machine-type=f1-micro`

Answer (score 14):

I created a vm on google cloud

```
gcloud compute instances create redis-forwarder --machine-type=f1-micro
```

then ssh into it and installed haproxy

```
sudo su
apt-get install haproxy
```

then updated the config file

```
/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

....existing file contents
frontend redis_frontend
  bind *:6379
  mode tcp
  option tcplog
  timeout client  1m
  default_backend redis_backend

 backend redis_backend
   mode tcp
   option tcplog
   option log-health-checks
   option redispatch
   log global
   balance roundrobin
   timeout connect 10s
   timeout server 1m
   server redis_server [MEMORYSTORE IP]:6379 check
```

restart haproxy

```
/etc/init.d/haproxy restart
```

I was then able to connect to memory store from my local machine for development

Answer (score 7):

You can spin up a Compute Engine instance and setup an haproxy using the following docker image [haproxy docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/haproxy/) then haproxy will forward your tcp requests to memorystore.

For example i want to access memorystore instance with ip 10.0.0.12 so added the following haproxy configs:

```
frontend redis_frontend
   bind *:6379
   mode tcp
   option tcplog
   timeout client  1m
   default_backend redis_backend

backend redis_backend
   mode tcp
   option tcplog
   option log-health-checks
   option redispatch
   log global
   balance roundrobin
   timeout connect 10s
   timeout server 1m
   server redis_server 10.0.0.12:6379 check
```

So now you can access memorystore from your local machine using the following command:

```
redis-cli -h <your-haproxy-public-ipaddress> -p 6379
```

Note: replace  with you actual haproxy ip address.

Hope that can help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

This post builds on earlier ones and should help you bypass firewall issues.

Create a virtual machine in the same region(and zone to be safe) as your Memorystore instance. On this machine:

- Add a network tag with which we will create a firewall rule to allow traffic on port 6379
- Add an external IP with which you will access this VM

SSH into this [machine](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances) and install haproxy

```
sudo su
apt-get install haproxy
```

add the following below existing config in the /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg file

```
frontend redis_frontend
   bind *:6379
   mode tcp
   option tcplog
   timeout client  1m
   default_backend redis_backend

backend redis_backend
   mode tcp
   option tcplog
   option log-health-checks
   option redispatch
   log global
   balance roundrobin
   timeout connect 10s
   timeout server 1m
   server redis_server [MEMORYSTORE IP]:6379 check
```

restart haproxy

```
/etc/init.d/haproxy restart
```

Now create a firewall [rule](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls) that allows traffic on port 6379 on the VM. Ensure:

- It has the same target tag as the networking tag we created on the VM.
- It allows traffic on port 6379 for the TCP protocol.

Now you should be able to connect remotely like so:

```
redis-cli -h [VM IP] -p 6379
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @Christiaan answered above, it almost worked for me but I needed a few other things to check to make it work well.

- Firstly, in my case, my Redis is running in a specific network other than `default` network, so I had to create the jumpbox inside the same network (let's call it `my-network`)
- Secondly, I needed to apply a firewall rule to open port 22 in that network.

So putting all my needed command it looks like this:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create default-allow-ssh --project=my-project  --network my-network --allow tcp:22 --source-ranges 0.0.0.0/0

gcloud compute instances create jump-box --machine-type=f1-micro --project my-project --zone europe-west1-b --network my-network

gcloud compute ssh jump-box  --project my-project --zone europe-west1-b -- -N -L 6379:10.177.174.179:6379
```

Then I have access to Redis locally on `6379`

Answer (score 0):

Memorystore does not allow connecting from local machines, other ways like from CE, GAE are expensive especially your project is small or in developing phase, I suggest you create a cloud function to execute memorystore, it's serverless service which means lower fee to execute. I wrote small [tool](https://github.com/AktskJerry/exec-cloud-memorystore) for this, the result is similar to run on local machine. You can check if help to you.