# Not able to connect to MemoryStore Redis C#

Tags: google-cloud-memorystore

I am attempting to use the new GCP MemoryStore Redis feature, however, i am unable to find a way to connect to it via StackExchange or something similar. It seems the sdk is meant to manage the instance itself, not for performing Redis based actions.

Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: Although connecting from C# via StackExchange client is not documented here (https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-flex), I believe you should be able to use configuration similar to this (https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration#basic-configuration-strings).
Also remember redis instance and the app/instance/cluster have to be in the same region and network for them to communicate. ". Can you please tell us which step is failing for you?

Comment: The application lives outside of GCP. I am trying to use it like you would any other redis instance.

Comment: This questions explains it better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281492/accessing-gcp-memorystore-from-local-machines, where they say a VPN connection might be required to do what you are trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as MemoryStore goes, this is not possible, externally. GCP has a hosted version of Redis, which i ended up using, and works great.