# Access Google MemoryStore from outside network

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-memorystore

Is there anyway to allow Google Memorystore to be accessible to the outside world and just whitelist connections by IP Address?

I have some off google services that need access to the redis but it doesnt seem possible to hit Memorystore with an IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the solution proposed in [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281492/accessing-gcp-memorystore-from-local-machines). This way, you would be using that Compute Engine instance as a proxy and you would just need to configure some firewall rules to only allow specific IP addresses to access that VM.

To put it in a few steps:

- Create your VM in the same VPC your Google Memorystore instance is using
- Add firewall rules to deny all traffic (ingress and egress) and other higher priority rules allowing all traffic (again, ingress and egress) from your desired IP addresses targeting your VPC
- Use port forwarding as explained in the [mentioned thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281492/accessing-gcp-memorystore-from-local-machines)

Comment: Thanks Pablo. I'll mark this the correct answer. However, for those who are looking for a solution - Digital Ocean now has a managed Redis server that defaults to open and then you can whitelist as so desired. It works great.