# Redis(Memorystore) clearing out keys

Tags: google-cloud-platform, express-session, google-cloud-memorystore

I am using express-sessions and Redis(Memorystore) 5.0 to save sessions and it appears Redis is clearing out all the keys(randomly and not at intervals) way before the TTL  on a key runs out. Leaving only a couple of backup entries

[image: here is a screenshot]

This entry should be valid for another week judging from the TTL.

I have never configured a Redis instance before and it is likely I misconfigured this one, some insight would be appreciated.

Also, this is what I get when I run monitor

[image]

Comment: Did you configured `maxmemory-policy` on your Memorystore instance? If so, it could be due to your instance memory being full and certain keys with TTL has to be evicted to make room for new writes even before it reaches TTL. See https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/redis-configs?_ga=2.233554072.-704563926.1616372152#maxmemory_policies

Comment: If not, then I suggest you connect to your Memorystore instance and run the [monitor](https://redis.io/commands/MONITOR) command and try to catch the reason behind the delete. Here's a doc how: https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance#connecting-compute-engine-redis-cli

Comment: I should add that I created a compute engine instance that I use to access Redis through an external IP and this behaviour does not Persist when I do not use it this way. But I would like to be able to access the Redis instance remotely.

Comment: I've looked up on the internet what are those scripts, I don't think they should be there as it appears to be a malicious script.  Also, you mentioned that this issue don't happen if you don't connect with your GCE instance. You should have your instance checked, or use a fresh instance to connect to Memorystore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid exposing your Memorystore instance through the external IP of your Compute Engine. Combined with the fact that
Memorystore instances currently requires [no authentication](https://issuetracker.google.com/152073004), this will lead to a vulnerability that
will allow anyone to read, write and execute scripts on your instance. On the worst case scenario, it will allow someone to mine cryptocurrency using your instance, hence causing a suspension on your project or account unfortunately.

There are multiple guides online to connect to Memorystore remotely. I suggest connecting through SSH by following this thread: [Accessing GCP Memorystore from local machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281492/accessing-gcp-memorystore-from-local-machines)

For reference, I will paste the answer here (credits to the person who posted it):

"If your Redis machine has internal IP address 10.0.0.3 you'd do:

```
gcloud compute instances create redis-forwarder --machine-type=f1-micro
gcloud compute ssh redis-forwarder -- -N -L 6379:10.0.0.3:6379
```

As long as you keep the ssh tunnel open you can connect to localhost:6379"