# How to connect to GCP Memorystore redis from local?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am able to access  GCP Memorystore Redis from gcp cloud run through vpc connector. But how can I do that from my localhost ?

Comment: **localhost** is a network that only exists inside your operating system. Edit your question to clarify what you are trying to accomplish. If you mean your computer outside Google Cloud you will need to forward your traffic using a VPN or port forwarding to a VPC. Example for port forwarding: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51614260/8016720

Comment: I need a local working environment to do development activities. I want to access Memorystore redis without deploying my code or container to any gcp service.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect from a localhost machine with [port forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance#connecting_from_a_local_machine_with_port_forwarding) and it can be helpful to connect to your Redis instance during development.

Create a compute engine instance by running the following command:

```
         gcloud compute instances create NAME --machine-type=f1-micro --zone=ZONE
```

Open a new terminal on your local machine.

To create an SSH tunnel that port forwards traffic through the Compute Engine VM, run the following command:

```
         gcloud compute ssh COMPUTE_VM_NAME --zone=ZONE -- -N -L 6379:REDIS_INSTANCE_IP_ADDRESS:6379
```

4. To test the connection, open a new terminal window and run the following command:

   ```
      redis-cli ping
   ```
5. The SSH tunnel remains open as long as you keep the terminal window with the SSH tunnel connection up and running.

I suggest you use the link for [setting up a development environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/building-app/environment-setup).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Redis as caching-only, or simple pub/sub, I would just spin up a local redis container for development.